# how to use pivot function in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark v 2.4 and I am trying to run pivot function in spark sql but it gives me error each time.

Table headers : `prof_sk, prod_sk, rep_sk, metric_sk, metric_value`

```
  select *
  from (
           select prof_sk, prod_sk, rep_sk
            from pivot_temp) as t
   PIVOT
   (
     SUM(metric_value) for metric_sk in (attainment, sales_trx, sales_nrx)) AS PivotTable
```

Sample Data before pivot:
[image]

Data after pivot required : [image]

and how to do unvipot as well via sparksql

Comment: what is the error, also please show few rows of input and desired output.

Comment: cannot resolve '`metric_sk`' given input columns

Answer (score 0):

- The inner query should contain all columns used by the pivot.
- The next error you could get might be about the type of metric_sk: as they are strings, they must be put in quotes.

Sometime like this (not tested):

```
select *  from (select prof_sk, prod_sk, rep_sk, metric_sk, metric_value   from pivot_temp) as t  PIVOT (SUM(metric_value) for metric_sk in ('attainment', 'sales_trx', 'sales_nrx')) AS PivotTable
```